# Order edit page broken

Tags: magento-1.8, orders, edit-order

For few orders, the order admin page is broken.
[image]

For other orders, page is working fine and normal without any issues. 
XML ERROR while turning on php errors

```
Warning: simplexml_load_string(): Entity: line 16: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document  in /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php on line 510

#0 [internal function]: mageCoreErrorHandler(2, 'simplexml_load_...', '/var/www/html/l...', 510, Array)
#1 /var/www/html/lib/Varien/Simplexml/Config.php(510): simplexml_load_string('loadString('loadFile('/var/www/html/a...')
#4 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(380): Mage_Core_Model_Config->loadBase()
#5 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(293): Mage_Core_Model_App->_initBaseConfig()
#6 /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(337): Mage_Core_Model_App->baseInit(Array)
#7 /var/www/html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#8 /var/www/html/index.php(94): Mage::run('', 'store')
#9 {main}
```

Comment: Go to index.php in root remove comment `#ini_set('display_error',1);` and check what is error.You will able to find error.

Comment: You don't need to edit the index.pho file. Just check your error logs in var/log in your Magento folder or your server's error logs

Comment: Nothing in logs related to this error.

Comment: When I am enabling display error, some xml parsing warning is appearing.

Comment: In that case, it only happens with some orders. It seems like an extension related issue. What do these orders have in common? Do they have the same shipping or payment method or something?

Comment: Update question with error

Comment: @PrashantValanda : Updated the question

Comment: @ArjenMiedema : Yes, it is related to a custom extension. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was due to some third party extension, when I disabled the third party extension from app/etc/modules the page appears fine. 
Then I wrote to the extension support team and they provided me the fix.

Answer (score 0):

In your xml file

First line start with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

No comment above it or no any space before it and Do not start with new line.

Not like below:

```
<!-- validators -->
<?xml version="1.0"?>
```